# combining accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

I've just stumbled across my first account here, back on Feb. 06, '12, answering the question 'As a guitarist, how can I learn to sight-read music?'

How can I combine that account with the present one. No point having the two.

Answer (score 2):

just use the [Contact link](https://music.stackexchange.com/contact) at the bottom to send a message to the CMs asking them to merge, and give them the URLs for your current and old account. They can check they are both valid and merge them for you.

Comment: Back in '12, I was unregistered, so old account details elude me. Help!

Comment: *'Back in '12...'* I feel so old now...

Comment: @Tim - if you have that old question, you can get the user URL from it. The CMs are very good at helping with this sort of thing.